# Traversing a tree while emptying it and returning the node

Tags: java

I just had a quick question about tree traversing. I wanted to know if there is a way to traverse a tree recursively, return a node, then make that node equal to zero.. effectively emptying the tree while returning all the nodes.

I have a recursive method for an in-order traversal and I have a feeling I need to code it somewhat similarly.

```
 private void iOrecursive(TreeNode present, StringBuilder str) {
    if(present == null) return;

    iOrecursive(present.left, str);
    str.append(present.key + "\n");
    iOrecursive(present.right, str); }




public String show() {
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   iOrecursive(root, sb);
   return sb.toString(); }
```

how can I make a separate method that does what the show() method does, but instead if gets the first node in the tree and returns it into a list, sets the current node to null, then goes onto the next one. Thanks in advance for any feedback!

Comment: Have you tried to do this? You've only provided us a 'show' method, not your attempt to implement a traverse-and-remove method. As you mention, the logic is similar so.... why not take a shot?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply, I've tried to do somewhat the same thing it's just I don't know how to set the present node to null after it has been returned

Comment: Just set it to null before returning the value? Please provide your attempted solution.